# How to deploy multiple C# Web API solution into the same IIS port?

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'd like to deploy multiple Web API Solution into one deployment on IIS, so I don't need to set new site and port for every Web API I've deployed.

I'm new to C# Web API, but as what I do in Java, I can create a .war of API project then deploy to Weblogic and choose which instance to deploy the .jar.  Either to multiple instance or specific instance.

At client side, I just need to access the Weblogic instance (by port number) and the correct URL of the API.

Is this applicable in IIS for C# Web API deployment?
Or do I need to forget the modular concept by include all API to the same C# Solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add application under the web site.

Short answer: 
Right click on your website -> click `Add Application` -> give it an `Alias` and path to another web API.  It will be available under `yourwebsite.com/Alias`

Also, you can read this.
https://docs.kentico.com/k11/installation/deploying-kentico-to-a-live-server/creating-virtual-directories-and-application-pools-in-iis-7-5-and-7-0